# Getting error while load document in alfresco

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I am facing problem while loading the document in alfresco share
If i click on particular document then got following error..

```
Alfresco    Web Script Status 500 - Internal Error

The Web Script /alfresco/wcs/api/node/workspace/SpacesStore/8d1911bc-7f93-4001-bfc6-3018886fdc51/content/thumbnails/webpreview has responded with a status of 500 - Internal Error.

500 Description:    An error inside the HTTP server which prevented it from fulfilling the request.
 Exception: org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException - 09280071 Read-Write transaction started within read-only transaction
```

How can I solve this error??

Thanks

Comment: Why are you trying to make changes to a document in a read-only transaction?

Comment: I did not configure anything to like read only transaction...

Comment: And what version of Alfresco are you using?

Comment: alfresco version - 4.2.f